# How to set up R environment for a team project?

Tags: r, git, github, jupyter-notebook, rnotebook

I am going to be in a team project. We do not have much time, so people will need to work at the same time on the project and quickly share their code. What would be the best way to do it?

I had two ideas: git and  R Jupyter Notebook

I know there is mergetool in git - although I have never used it. Can somebody comment it? 
What are the recommendations?

R Notebook is better in terms of sharing code but I do not imagine though 2 people writing code in Jupyter at the time.

With git people can work independently and simultaneously but can be problems with  people committing changes at the same time.

Any recommendations are welcomed, I am quite new to this still.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that if you *commit small and commit often*, you shouldn't have that much of a trouble with git.

I feel that merge conflicts often happen due to misusage of git, that's just my two cents. :)

Comment: you were right, git worked very well for our project :)

Comment: Glad to hear it. ;)